# SO "Ask Question" UI isn't displaying properly for me

Tags: support, bug

I'm seeing the following in SO since yesterday afternoon. I tried all the usual suspects...logging in and out, clearing the browser cache, restarting my browser, and even this morning, after restarting my machine (cold boot)...

If I go to edit a previous question, tools appear and formatted text window updates properly. This only appears to be happening with new questions. Other SE sites (including SO meta) are working just fine. There's no uproar about this on meta, so I suspect it's just some anomaly with me.

However, I'm baffled.

Anyone else experiencing this problem? Any ideas how to fix it? Win 7, IE8, JavaScript Enabled, cache cleared (automatic on shutdown and confirmed). No apparent JavaScript errors.

[image: What I'm seeing on SO]

Comment: What browser? What operating system? Any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `F5` ? Could be a cache issue?

Comment: JavaScript enabled? Cache deleted and refreshed?

Comment: Does it happen with IE9? Officially, we do not support IE8 and under.

Comment: All answered with an edit...the company hasn't rolled out IE9 yet, so I'm stuck with IE8. Sigh. That may be my issue. Although my browser is set to auto-delete the cache on exit, I've not tried `ctrl+f5`. I'll give that a shot/

Comment: Yep, still happening after `ctrl+F5` and still ONLY in SO under ie8.

Comment: @dwwilson66 - this is happening only on SO, but other sites work fine in IE8? If so can you check the dev console for errors?